# Python and AzureCosmosDB: Query in command must target a single shard key

Tags: python, mongodb, azure-cosmosdb, mongoengine

I have these two models in my python code:

Media

```
class Media(EmbeddedDocument):
type = StringField()
url = URLField()
```

Playlist

```
class Playlist(DynamicDocument):
id = StringField(db_field="id", primary_key=True, required=True)
name = StringField()
media = ListField(field=EmbeddedDocumentField(Media))
meta = {'collection': 'playlist'}
```

I create the playlist collection in Azure DBCosmos (using the web UI), assigning the id of the playlist model as the shard key. There is no problem when reading the database through my python code using mongoEngine lybrary but when I tried to insert some document in the following way:

```
mediatest2 = Media(type = "image", url= "https://steemediadev001.blob.core.windows.net/eemedia/life.jpg")
result = Playlist(id='1', media = [mediatest2]).save()
```

I get the following error:

***Query in command must target a single shard key***

Does anyone knows what is going on? Thanks in advance,

Excatter

Comment: What is the command and what is the query being referenced?

Comment: I don´t know about the command but the query is the save() part, the error only tell's me the message I have left here